# OAuth 1.0 in console application

Tags: java, oauth, console

I would like to create an application which is a essential a console command line tool, written in java, that needs to access an API using OAuth 1.0.

I can see there are useful libraries around such as Scribe and JOauth which help with the negotiation, there are scenarios which work with web applications and android applications.

After searching, I cannot find any examples of where a console application can start the default web browser, and then get the authorization token back. I see that the Google app engine tool for publishing/updating GAE apps does do this. Can anyone provide any example code of how this can be done or some links to helpful documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch the user's default web browser by using the [java.awt.Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class. For example:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://www.relevantserver.com");
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

Comment: but can I then intercept the URL I get back to read the token? I have checked the methods on this, and there are no "read" methods for the browser.

Comment: Well, you could always instantiate a Jetty server at a random port, and have the browser redirect there...